# Redirect not working, it doesn't redirect to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with **Redirect**, it doesn't work in my code. It stays on the same page without redirection.

Can you tell me why?

---

Source code (without doesn't matter code):

```
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

class Test extends Component {

    onError = err => {
        if (err.response && err.response.status === 500) {
            return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/',
                state: {error: err}
            }}/>;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? Where is `onError` being called? Have you confirmed that your return statement is being called, and that the 'if' statement isn't causing it to be skipped?

Answer (score 0):

My code is ugly. The main idea is to wrap Test class to [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) which pass route props to class Test.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function Test = () => withRouter(
  class Test extends React.Component {
    onError = (error) => {
      const { response } = error;
      if (response && response.status === 500) {
        const { history } = this.props;
        
        history.replace('/', { error });
      }
    }
    
    render() {
      return null;
    }
  }
);
```